# Random noticing of user account numbers

Tags: discussion, users, fun

Has anyone else just counted up from -1 in the https://stackoverflow.com/users/XXXX (where X is numbers)?

Why do regular Stack Overflow users start at 1 rather than the usual 0? Was someone who knew Cobol on the team? ;)

Also, anyone else seen https://stackoverflow.com/users/10 ?

And why are there random gaps in the account numbers? Is this just where accounts were deleted?

Comment: I would think quite a number of the first few tens of IDs might be that of test accounts and were deleted/disblaed subsequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Has anyone else just counted up from
>   -1 in the https://stackoverflow.com/users/XXXX 
>   (where X is numbers)?

Not me

> Why do regular Stack Overflow users
>   start at 1 rather than the usual 0?
>   Was someone who knew Cobol on the
>   team? ;)

Because `if (0)` returns false; this is usually undesidered and may lead to surprising effects if not considered. Additionally an unregistered user could be considered by the system as having ID 0 (and now `if (0)` makes sense).

Also I don't know about you but if I'm counting how many people there are in the room I start with 1, not 0. And I'm a hardcore C++ programmer, but starting counting from 0 outside of C++/arrays seems silly.

> And why are there random gaps in the
>   account numbers? Is this just where
>   accounts were deleted?

Yes

Comment: Counting from 0 outside of arrays might be silly, but it would mean I wouldn't always have to subtract 1 from `array.length`

Answer (score 5):

The numbers would start at 1 because it's a database, and databases, in my experience, start at 1 for the autogenerated primary key.

I'm with Koper, I haven't navigated the users in numerical order either.

Answer (score 4):

The User Id is represented by an auto-incrementing `int` in the database.

The StackExchange software uses SQL Server as their DBMS system. SQL Server uses `IDENTITY` to specify an auto-incrementing field. The default parameters for `IDENTIDY` is `seed 1`, `increment 1`.

In English, this means that the first value is `1`, and the next value is generated by incrementing `1` to the previous.

> [`IDENTITY` (Property)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: How does Stack Overflow generate this consecutive IDs if their database is obviously distributed? I mean, having a single service responsible for the ID generation seems to be a bottleneck to me, how do they do it then? Thank you!